# NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "stream"

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After upgrading a few items in my package.json I'm all of a sudden getting:

```
Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "stream", relative to: /app/tns_modules/

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.naturesnotebookmobile/files/app/tns_modules/parse5/lib/parser/stream.js', line: 3, column: 22
```

Any ideas? Previously I was at 2.0.0 for all the angular stuff and it was working then. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.7",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.1.0",
    ... a few other things here...
    "node-geocoder": "^3.15.0",
    "oauth-signature": "^1.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.3.0",
    "util": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.16.0",
    "babel-types": "6.16.0",
    "babylon": "6.12.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of **nativescript-angular** does **not require** the `@angular/platform-server` 
dependency. That dependency uses a different version of the parse5 which is causing this issue.

Simply remove it.

Comment: I confirm, this solved the issue for me as well. It would've been nice if NativeScript developers pointed this out more clearly somewhere, unless I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: It would be a good idea indeed. For now you can follow this (https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng) repo and its package.json (https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng/blob/master/package.json) which is being updated with each release.